# Saving a isolate prop image with shadow to png

Tags: png

I'm shooting singular objects in studio and would like to save them isolated with their shadow information and a transparent background as a png.

Is there a tutorial someone could point me to to do this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: PNG is almost always the wrong format for photographs. Could you explain why you need this as a PNG?

Comment: jpeg doesn't do transparancy, .psd is application-specific and tiff is bulky?

Comment: I not believe is a wrong format. It is quite useful. It is a specific type of delivery format.

Comment: @PhilipKendall I need to deliver png to designers so they can add their own background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting.

I come from a 3D rendering background besides photography. So I am used to think as separated layers. My approach would be:

- Cut the object in one image without the shadow.
- Depending on the background, using all the image with shadow as a separate layer. Probably convert it to grayscale if the background is not neutral white.

We can go several ways for the shadows.

1. Using this grayscale image with a blending mode multiply and using it below the object layer.
   This is faster but only if you work with a layered method.

[image]

2. Using this image as a transparency mask for a total black layer. You need to invert the image. This second option is the one that can give you a single PNG with shadows included.

[image]

You can play with the levels of this mask and the curves, to adjust the intensity of the shadow and to clean the background.

You probably need to paint a bit on the borders of this mask so it does not show behind the clipped object.

[image]

---

An additional explanation for The comment about the mask.

1. Open your image, and make it a new layer.
2. Add a layer mask
3. Alt+click on it, and paste the image again inside. You have now a transparent image based on the information on the image. But the information is backwards, you need to invert it in order to work.

Apply this method to a black plate as described in the steps above.

[image]

Your shadow layer should look like this:
[image]

I have not masked the red dot layer, I only did the shadow part.

Comment: I am struggling with Rafael's answer as there are some steps I am not familiar with. Particularly using the inverted image as a mask for the solid layer. This seems to not be working for me.

Comment: @Lewis Logan, I added some steps at the end of the post for you.